# Cpagination  с реляционным запросом работает не корректно

Tags: yii

Здравствуйте. В экшене есть след. код:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with=array(
            'rel1',
            'rel2'=>array(
                'condition'=>'type_id =:id',
                'params'=>array(':id'=>$id),
                'together'=>true,
            ),
        );
$criteria->distinct = true;
$count = MyModel::model()->count($criteria);

$pages=new CPagination($count);
$pages->pageSize=9;
$pages->applyLimit($criteria);

$model= MyModel::model()->findAll($criteria);
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$model,
            'pages'=>$pages,
        ));
```

Далее вывожу в представлении данные обычным циклом и вывожу саму пагинацию через CLinkPager.

Проблема: Вместо того чтобы выводить на каждой странице по девять записей, пагинация выводит в общем 9 записей и разбивает и их по страницам как попало.
Cам запрос в базу срабатывает корректно, получает нужные записи в нужном количестве.
Проблема начинается когда цепляю CPagination.

Как решить данную проблему, что делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй зaюзать CActiveDataProvider и вывести через zii.widgets.CListView. !не выводите данные в цикле сами, это плохо!